# SetAttribute Class of a dynamically created element - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a hyperlink element dynamically and set its attribute class so when it is clicked it will trigger a function.

Here is the code for dynamically creating the hyperlink element:

```
editLink = document.createElement("a");
editLink.setAttribute("class", "edit-button");
```

This is what should happen when the link was clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.edit-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.overlay').show().css({'top': scrollTop + 'px'});
    });
});
```

But nothing happens when it is clicked. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Use **event delegation** ... instead of `$('.edit-button').click(....` try `$(document.body).on('click','.edit-button',function(){....`

Comment: you should call document.ready function again after setting class dynamically or do as @KartikeyaKhosla said

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: What could be a problem is something as simple as your HTML or CSS. Please provide them so we have a complete picture of your situation. We have no idea what or where `.edit-button` or `.overlay` is.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are appending the created element with body. I make this changes and it is working fine

```
var editLink = document.createElement("a");
editLink.setAttribute("class", "edit-button");
editLink.innerHTML = "Click"; // added text for testing
window.document.body.appendChild(editLink); // Appending to body

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.edit-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
   alert('1')
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.overlay').show().css({'top': scrollTop + 'px'});
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/7wc948b7/5/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var editLink = document.createElement("a");
editLink.setAttribute("class", "edit-button");
editLink.innerHTML  = 'click';
document.body.appendChild(editLink);

$(function() {
    $('.edit-button').on('click',function(event){
    alert('clicked');
    event.preventDefault(); 
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('.overlay').show().css({'top': scrollTop + 'px'});
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s718ay3g/1/

Answer (score 0):

[Event Delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) is the way to do it.

When you add event to `.edit-button` directly, at the time of loading the document, browser attaches that event listener to only the currently existing `.edit-button` elements. It doesn't get executed automatically for the newly created elements with the same class.

What you could do is put your event biding and listener code in a function and call it each time you add a new element to the DOM. But that's considered a bad practice.

Welcome, Event Delegation.

The idea is to attach the event to a parent/ancestor element which is not dynamic and trigger the event only when the event target is your specified element( matched with some sort of selector like class or ID).

In your case, the updated event binding code would look like this.

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".edit-button", function(){
    //whatever you want to do in here.
});
```

and then, you can continue to add classes to newly created elements like you did...

```
var editLink = document.createElement("a");
editLink.setAttribute("class", "edit-button");
```

The event would still work.

This way you only attach the event once.

If your buttons/links are going to be contained in a container `div` or something similar, attach the event to that container instead of body.

```
$(".class-of-the-container").on("click", ".edit-button", function(){
    //whatever you want to do in here.
});
```